# Mi consulta solo muestra los Integer, hago una consulta de tipo String y me marca error

Tags: windows-phone

¿Cómo  mostrar una  búsqueda  de tipo `string` en Windows Phone 8.1.?
Este es el código  que tengo, con este  código sólo me muestra los tipo `integer`.

```
      private async void Btn_buscarUsuario(object sender, RoutedEventArgs 
      {

        var existing = Db_Helper.SearchUserCode(txtcodigo.Text);

        if (existing != null)
        {
            txtcodigo.Text = existing.Code;
            txtusuario.Text = existing.User;
            txtcontrasena.Text = existing.Contrasena;
            CboStatus.SelectedValue = existing.Status;
            txtemail.Text = existing.Email;

        }
```

Este es el query que tengo:

```
      public Usuarios SearchUserCode( string Usercode)
      {
        using ( var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
             var existingCodeUser = dbConn.Query<Usuarios>("select * from  Usuarios where Code=" + Usercode).FirstOrDefault();
            return existingCodeUser; 
        }
       }
```

Comment: a q te refieres con que solo te muestra enteros? que error te marca?

Comment: por ejemplo  yo hago  esta  consulta a  mi base de datos  1237890  una  persona  registrada   con ese código me   lo muestra  correctamente,  si yo hago  una  consulta  de  un código de esta  menera  ADBN6789  es donde no me  marca  el error.

Comment: bueno pueden haber varios problemas... pero no es lo mismo hacer una consulta a columna numerica q a una de tipo string..y los string van entre comillas!

Comment: si puse entre comillas  usercode , de todas  manera  no me  corrige el error

Comment: y la columna de que tipo es? y por favor podrias ser especifica, decir que error te marca y en que linea?

Comment: es de  tipo string

Comment: Ok sofia.. limpiemos esto que no es un chat.. Agrega toda esta informacion a la pregunta, y borramos todos los comentarios y especifica claramente el problema, y yo preguntaba por la columna de la base de datos. Marca la linea q tira el error, el tipo de error, la info de la BD asi podemos ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está ocurriendo es que al pasar el valor de la búsqueda a la sentencia SQL, no la colocas como una cadena de caracteres (encerrada en comillas simples), ni como parámetro (que es lo recomendable).

La solución *fácil* para tu problema es simplemente encerrarla entre comillas, por ejemplo:

```
      public Usuarios SearchUserCode( string Usercode)
      {
        using ( var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
             var existingCodeUser = dbConn.Query<Usuarios>("select * from  Usuarios where Code ='" + Usercode + "'").FirstOrDefault();
            return existingCodeUser; 
        }
       }
```

Ya con esto desaparecerá el *error* que estás viendo ahora, pero tu aplicación será vulnerable a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Mi recomendación es que en lugar de *embeber* el valor dentro de la sentencia SQL, utilices una consulta parametrizada, puedes basarte en este ejemplo para adaptar tus clases/código a la idea:

```
SQLiteCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from Tabla where Campo = @ValorBuscar";
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ValorBuscar", elPeligrosoDatoDelUsuario));
```

Encontrarás más razones para utilizar consultas parametrizadas en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20017707/255257) de SO en inglés.